# Default input states of qubits to quantum circuits

Tags: quantum-state, nielsen-and-chuang, initialization

> It is conventional to assume that the state input to the circuit is a
>   computational basis state, usually the state consisting of all
>   $|0\rangle$s. This rule is broken frequently in the literature on
>   quantum computation and quantum information, but it is considered
>   polite to inform the reader when this is the case.

What does this mean?

**Source**:  M. Nielsen and I. Chuang. Quantum Computation and Quantum Information. Cambridge UniversityPress, 2000. (1.3.4 Quantum Circuits)

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: Are you just confused about the notation? The starting state could be anything depending upon the basis, it is just convenient to use $|0\rangle$s. The book just says that it may be different and that will be informed to the reader. That is not even a scientific issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have some quantum algorithms assuming you prepared a special input state which is not represented as a superposition of bitstrings.

For example, you can just say you start in the $| + \rangle$ state for all your qubits.
Another one is starting in a state where you have encoded your input in the amplitudes of a quantum state (this type of encoding is called amplitude encoding). This is used in quantum linear system solvers (originally HHL) to input a vector in a quantum form to solve a linear system.